# Recover MongoDB from AWS Server (ns files corrupt? not downloadable?)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, recovery, database

I do have multiple AWS EC2 Servers all running mongodb instances. Its all well, but just one of the servers seems to act weired. If I try downloading the database (using sftp and it works on the other servers, so there should be no problem with the settings on that end), its all well for most of the .0 .1 .2 .. files, but one of those numbered files and most importantly the .ns file produce an error when downloading.

I tried restarting and also could not really find anything useful on the web. It seems there is no real way to regenerate the .ns file and I have no clue why the instance suddenly (started at the weekly backup like 2 weeks ago) keeps acting up. All the others work well, same setup.

Hope this is the right section. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: sorry, its not really clear from your question what the problem is.  Could you post more information about the error?  If you're running this on AWS can you not just kill off the server that misbehaves and create a new one?

Comment: Did you stop mongod on the server from which you are trying to copy the data files?  If not, they will be corrupted.

Comment: The problem has been solved. It was some weired memory issue. Thank you!